# Use of %20 as a separator in regular expression

Tags: regex

I have the following text

```
 test test2  test3 
test20+test21+test22
test30%20test31%20test32%20%20test33
```

using regular expression, I would like to get the TESTS words.

Until now, I've got this `[^\s\+]?[\w]+` which succeed in the first two lines but I cann'ot work out the **%20** ... any help please  ?

Comment: Are you trying to get all words that start with `test` or all words that are separated by spaces or space-like characters?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you need. Please explicitly show your desired output matches. Is `/test\d+/` what you want?

Comment: Sorry about being late, @HunterMcMillen this is just a sample of text, I am looking to get everything in between SPACE, PLUS, or %20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To not match the `%20` but do match the rest of the words, you could use an alternation `|` first matching what you don't want to keep and a capturing group capturing what you do want to keep.

```
%20|(\w+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GPGd6D/1)

Comment: @Sim You could prepend and append matching `\s*` for example `%20|\s*([\w+]+)\s*` https://regex101.com/r/ST4wxz/1 and match the `+` as well as `\w`

Comment: That is almost it, but I don't need the `%20`

Comment: I am loooking for everything which TEXT that is not `%20` or `+` or `SPACE`

Comment: @Sim That is what the pattern in the answer does. It gets the data that you want in the first capturing group. In https://regex101.com/r/GPGd6D/1 the groups are highlighted in green.What is the tool or language?

Comment: python RE, the solution you provided, matches either `%20` or the word , well I will dig deeper in it, thank you for your answer :)

Comment: @Sim In Python you can do it like this https://ideone.com/Ap4t81